# MySQL сравнение 2 таблиц, и заполнение третий на основании различий

Tags: mysql, сравнение

Есть 3 таблицы:

```
NewData; OldDara; DifData.
```

Таблицы `NewData` и `OldData` имеют одинаковый набор колонок:

```
Email; Имя; Фамилия; Телефон; Должность.
```

Таблица `DifData` имеет следующие колонки:

```
Email; ИмяИзминившегосяАтрибута(имя столбца); СтароеЗначениеАтрибута; НовоеЗначениеАтрибута.
```

Задача:

Каждый день, таблица `NewData` очищается от данных и в неё заносятся свежие данные о сотрудниках (столбцов на самом деле намного больше чем в примере). Есть столбец с уникальным значением `Email`.

Далее нужно сравнить 2 таблицы `NewData` и `OldData` на различающиеся значения столбцов в каждом поле, и записать эти различия в третью таблицу.

Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Cron как вариант

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Большое Вам спасибо, особенно kld, твой код очень помог, далее его еще оптимизировал:
Сначала получил в массив название столбцов исходной таблицы и далее на основании массива подставил их в твой код.

```
for ($i= 0; $i -ne $res.Count; $i++)
{
$q_dif_data +="
                SELECT now(),UserPrincipalName,'$($res[$i]['field'])',users_new_data.$($res[$i]['field']),users_old_data.$($res[$i]['field'])
                FROM users_new_data 
                INNER JOIN users_old_data USING(UserPrincipalName)
                WHERE users_old_data.$($res[$i]['field'])<>users_new_data.$($res[$i]['field'])
                UNION" 
}
#____ Сравнили значения в таблицах с новыми данными и старыми данными


##### Вносим различающиеся данные в таблицу "test"
$q_dif_data = "INSERT INTO  test(DateOfEvent,UserPrincipalName,Parameter_name,New_value,Old_value) " + $q_dif_data
$q_dif_data = $q_dif_data.TrimEnd("UNION")
$sql.CommandText = $q_dif_data
$sql.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте типо этого

```sql
INSERT INTO (Email, ИмяИзминившегосяАтрибута(имя столбца), СтароеЗначениеАтрибута, НовоеЗначениеАтрибута)

SELECT Email, colonka, imyaOld, imyaNew 
FROM (
SELECT Email, 'Имя' colonka, o.Имя imyaOld, n.Имя imyaNew
FROM NewData n
WHERE Email NOT IN 
( 
  SELECT Email 
  FROM OldData
) o

UNION

SELECT Email, 'Имя', Имя, p.Имя, q.Имя 
FROM OldData p
WHERE Email NOT IN 
( 
  SELECT Email 
  FROM NewData
) q
) w
```

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle][1]
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ba330/1/0

```
CREATE TABLE newdata (
email varchar(100) NOT NULL,
name varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
surname varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
phone varchar(100) Default NULL);

INSERT INTO newdata values 
('a@a.ru','Ivan','Petrov','13-33'),
('b@a.ru','Petr','Petrov','13-35'),
('c@a.ru','Sidr','Sidorov','13-33');

CREATE TABLE olddata(
email varchar(100) NOT NULL,
name varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
surname varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
phone varchar(100) Default NULL);

INSERT INTO olddata VALUES 
('a@a.ru','Petr','Petrov','13-33'),
('b@a.ru','Petr','Sidorov','13-35'),
('c@a.ru','Sidr','Sidorov','13-33');

CREATE TABLE difdata(
email varchar(100) NOT NULL,
colname varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
olddata varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
newdata varchar(100) Default NULL);

INSERT INTO difdata (email,colname,olddata,newdata)
SELECT email,'name',olddata.name,newdata.name 
FROM newdata
INNER JOIN olddata USING(email)
WHERE olddata.name<>newdata.name

UNION

SELECT email,'surname',olddata.surname,newdata.surname 
FROM newdata
INNER JOIN olddata USING(email)
WHERE olddata.surname<>newdata.surname

UNION

SELECT email,'phone',olddata.phone,newdata.phone 
FROM newdata
INNER JOIN olddata USING(email)
WHERE olddata.phone<>newdata.phone;
```

Сколько полей проверять на изменение, столько и UNION.